# В чем разнице между двумя модулями в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

Какая разница между двумя модулями в Python?

Для примера я взял pickle но есть и другие модули подобного вида, что лучше и когда применять, дайте совет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Модуль `pickle` сразу импортирует `_pickle` , если есть такая возможность. `_pickle` это [c](/questions/tagged/c) оптимизированная версия `pickle`

Из [исходников модуля `pickle`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/pickle.py#L1598-L1613):

```
# Use the faster _pickle if possible
try:
    from _pickle import (
        PickleError,
        PicklingError,
        UnpicklingError,
        Pickler,
        Unpickler,
        dump,
        dumps,
        load,
        loads
    )
except ImportError:
    Pickler, Unpickler = _Pickler, _Unpickler
    dump, dumps, load, loads = _dump, _dumps, _load, _loads
```

В Python 2 `_pickle` была также известна как `cPickle`.

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191859/what-difference-between-pickle-and-pickle-in-python-3)